# Add props to numbers in ES2015 strict mode

Tags: javascript

I'd like to be able to do something like the following

```
console.log(a, typeof a); // prints "3 'number'"
console.log(typeof a.mymethod()); // prints  'foobar'
```

In non-strict mode this is possible (at least in Node), but strict mode in ECMAScript 2015 forbids setting properties on primitive values ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode)).

Is there any way I can fake this, say using `Proxy` or property descriptors, or anything like that?

Comment: Can't proxy a primitive either. Nor will any of the `Object` static methods work. Suspect this isn't possible in strict mode. Closest you can probably get is the [Symbol.toPrimitive](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/toPrimitive) well-known Symbol. You can make it so that coercing an object to a number will be a specific number, e.g. `+{} === 3`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is set to use ES2015 / strict mode and appears to do the trick:

```js
'use strict';

var a = 3;
Number.prototype.mymethod = function() { alert("foobar") };

a.mymethod();
```

Comment: It isn't what I meant, but it is what I asked, so you'll get the answer, although modifying the prototype is nothing but a hack :-)